# clickable QMenu triggered event not working - python

Tags: python, pyside

You'll see in the image attached below I want to make it so users can click on Laura (Which is a QMenu) and it fire and event. Much like a regular action would.

I'm dynamically creating the sub menus based on the hierarchy seen below. However I want all the sub-menus to be clickable except from 'Kids'.

What's odd is the 'hover' event fires but not the trigger event? Why would this be?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Main Widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # formatting
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # context menu
        self.main_menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu("Kids")
        self.main_menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu)

        tree = [
            {
                "parent" : "Chris",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "parent" : "Doug",
                        "children" : []
                    },
                    {
                        "parent" : "Michelle",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "parent" : "Susan",
                                "children" : []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "parent" : "Laura",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "parent" : "Michael",
                        "children" : []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

        self.build_sub_menu( self.sub_menu, tree )

        # widgets        
        self.factionsList = QtGui.QListWidget()
        # signal
        self.factionsList.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.factionsList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu_factions)
        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.factionsList, 1, 0)
        self.show()

    def add_menu_item(self, menu, branch):
        parent = branch["parent"]
        sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        item = menu.addMenu(sub_menu)
        item.triggered.connect(self.menu_action)
        item.hovered.connect(self.menu_action)
        print item

        for c in branch["children"]:
            self.add_menu_item( sub_menu, c)

    def build_sub_menu(self, menu, tree):
        for branch in tree:
            self.add_menu_item(menu, branch)

    def menu_action(self):
        print "Event"
        print self.sender().text()

    def on_context_menu_factions(self, pos):
        self.main_menu.exec_( QtGui.QCursor.pos() )

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWidget()
    res = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `QMenu` docs say of the `triggered` signal:

> Note: This signal is emitted for the main parent menu in a hierarchy. Hence, only the parent menu needs to be connected to a slot; sub-menus need not be connected

I guess that's because it is a UI convention that clicking on sub-menus does nothing: they open on hover and can't do anything other than open.  Your desired behaviour is unusual and I think it's going to need sub-classing `QMenu` if you need the `triggered` signal.

You could try connecting to the `aboutToShow` signal instead.

Another alternative would be to add some kind of "." action to each sub-menu representing the parent sub-menu action.